# Nickname isn't changing in discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.nick == f"[AFK] {message.author.name}":
        print("AFK Guy detected")
        who = message.author
        await who.edit(nick=f"{message.author.name}")
        await message.channel.send(f"Hey, {message.author.mention} welcome back, I removed your AFK.")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

When a user is AFK and comes back and send a message it doesn't rechange his name or do anything
Why is that?

Comment: Is "AFK Guy Detected" ever printed to console?

Comment: It's never printing

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it worked!

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.nick.startswith("[AFK]"):
        print("AFK Guy detected")
        who = message.author
        await who.edit(nick=f"{message.author.name}")
        await message.channel.send(f"Hey, {message.author.mention} welcome back, I removed your AFK.")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

It probably was the space between `[AFK]` and `{message.author.name}`. I have also added a `.startswith`, which checks if it starts with "[AFK]". It's just a bit better.

Comment: Sorry, my code wasn't finished there. The website crashed. Also make sure have the newest discord.py installed

Comment: I have the newest discord.py

Comment: Still not even printing anything

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Can you do `pip show discord` in command prompt and tell me the version?

Comment: the version is 1.7.3